# Excel Macro Different File name after Zip Extract

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Here's my code:

```
Sub TestRun()

   ' Define variables
    Dim file As String, folder As String
    ' Define working directory

folder = "E:\MainFolder\Appointments\"

 ' Define type of file to search for
    file = Dir(folder & "*.zip")

ZipPath = "E:\MainFolder\Appointments\" & file

    Call UnZip(folder, ZipPath) 
End Sub
```

What I want to to have a different file name after extract.  I want it to be appointments.csv instead of file

Comment: Maybe `CsvPath = Replace(ZipPath, ".zip", ".csv")` ...? That's strictly a crystal ball shot-in-the-dark but there isn't enough information to speculate further.

Comment: Is it possible to extract data from google analytics use VBA scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply rename your file using the `Name` function after extracting it

```
Name folder & oldFilename As folder & newFilename
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I did.  Thanks :)